# how to show special characters on my site?

Tags: html

I am currently working on a site that connects a DB and bring the information, some of this information has special characteres because is in polish languague, for example, in the database I have this one ę and I get e printed at my web,I already added the meta

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">
```

but doesnt work, only if I write & #281; which is not pract and needs a lot of work, my question is if somebody did this , get the character, like ę, and print it just like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that:

- the data really is in ISO-8859-2
- the data isn't be corrupted by the configuration of the database
- the HTTP headers aren't claiming the data is encoded a different way
- whatever you are using to pull the data out of the database isn't transcoding it

You should also ditch ISO-8859-2 (as it is *very* legacy) and move to UTF-8.

Comment: In the database, if you're using `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`, I believe that you'll need to use `NVARCHAR` or `NTEXT`  (But I could be wrong)

Comment: Thank you... I was trying adding data locally to a file only and just to check if works... but kept printing "e" I have this before my body

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//PL" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="pl">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">

Comment: Did you rewrite the DTD in Polish, if so you should change the URL? The public identifier for HTML 4.01 has EN in it, not PL. The Doctype is part of the HTML document, not the HTTP headers (which don't exist in a local file). You can't use the `<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">` syntax in HTML 4 either.

Comment: @jpganz18, the odds are that the HTTP server specifies an encoding other than ISO-8859-2 *or* you did not actually save the data as ISO-8859-2 encoding. Posting the URL would seem necessary for an analysis.

Comment: Thanks... I have tried doing this <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//PL" "w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="pl"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">
</head> then later insert the ę as a character (not like &###; but still doesnt work) Quentin, if that charset doesnt work in HTML 4... where can I use it? does it work in 5?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Unicode entity. &#xxxx; where xxxx is the Unicode value for the character.

Comment: Thank you, Ive tried with that, but its not so practic, and the data is stored in a DB like that...isnt any other way?